# KnockoutJS group + sort by date

Tags: knockout.js, group-by

I've got a set of Posts, like:

```
self.posts = ko.observableArray([
    {
        id : 1,
        is_stickey: false,
        date: '2014-09-01',
        content: 'demo content'
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        is_stickey: true,
        date: '2014-09-02',
        content: 'demo content'
    },
    // etcetera...
]
```

This set is augmented using infinite scrolling. In other words, additional items are pushed into it later.

I'm trying to find an efficient (read: fast, without unnecessary iterations) way to do the following:

- Group Posts by date
- Sort posts by is_stickey (ascending) + date (descending)
- In case 'is_stickey' changes, the post should animate to its new position

I'm thinking of using a Computed Observable to convert data into an Object as follows:

```
{
    'stickey' : [
        {
            id : 2,
            is_stickey: true,
            date: '2014-09-02',
            content: 'demo content'
        },
        {
            id : 3,
            is_stickey: true,
            date: '2014-08-26',
            content: 'demo content'
        }
    ],
    '2014-09-01' : [
        {
            id : 1,
            is_stickey: false,
            date: '2014-09-01',
            content: 'demo content'
        },
        {
            id : 4,
            is_stickey: false,
            date: '2014-09-01',
            content: 'demo content'
        }
    ],
    '2014-08-14' : [
        {
            id : 5,
            is_stickey: false,
            date: '2014-08-14',
            content: 'demo content'
        },
        {
            id : 6,
            is_stickey: false,
            date: '2014-08-14,
            content: 'demo content'
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately I'm a bit stuck in solving this:

1. Will KnockoutJS be able to iterate over this object?
2. Can it sort the Object keys like this?
3. Can I hook into the beforeMove/afterMove to make it animate when 'is_stickey' changes?
4. And most importantly; is this the right way to do it at all? Efficiency and speed is of great importance to me.

*Update*

The following result (View) is what I have in mind:

```
*sticky*
  Id 2 demo content
  Id 3 demo content
*2014-09-01*
  Id 1 demo content
  Id 4 demo content
*2014-08-14*
  Id 5 demo content
  Id 6 demo content
```

Comment: on sorting you can sort the observableArray using [search plugin](https://github.com/raheelshan/knockout-search/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with search plugin.

sample data

```
var arr = [
        {
            id : 2,
            is_stickey: true,
            date: '2014-09-02',
            content: 'demo content'
        },{
            id : 3,
            is_stickey: true,
            date: '2014-08-26',
            content: 'demo content'
        },{
            id : 1,
            is_stickey: false,
            date: '2014-09-01',
            content: 'demo content'
        },
        {
            id : 4,
            is_stickey: false,
            date: '2014-09-01',
            content: 'demo content'
        },{
            id : 1,
            is_stickey: false,
            date: '2014-08-14',
            content: 'demo content'
        },
        {
            id : 4,
            is_stickey: false,
            date: '2014-08-14,
            content: 'demo content'
        }
]

var vm = function vm(){
    var self = this
    self.List = ko.observableArray(arr)

    self.GroupByDate = function(){
        var myobject = ko.search.setData(self.List()) 
        var groupByDate = myobject.order('date').get()    
        self.List([])
        self.List(groupByDate)
    }

    self.SortPosts = function(){
        var myobject = ko.search.setData(self.List()) 
        var sorted = myobject.order('is_stickey').order('date').get()    
        self.List([])
        self.List(sorted)   
    }   
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm())
```

And

```
<div data-bind="foreach:List">
    <span>Date</span><span data-bind="text:date"></span>
    <span>Content</span><span data-bind="text:content"></span>
    <span>Sticky</span><span data-bind="text:is_stickey"></span><br />
</div>

<input type="button" data-bind="click:GroupByDate" value="Group By Post">
<input type="button" data-bind="click:SortPosts" value="Sort">
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dy0k2c23/1/)

Comment: The Grouping function is different than I had in mind. Besides that, my actual problem is combining the grouping with the sorting. I've updated my question for more clarity.